# Joomla/JomSocial Rewrite a phrase in a url

Tags: .htaccess, url, joomla, url-rewriting, jomsocial

I am building a Joomla 3 site with JomSocial.

A feature in JomSocial is "friends" but we would prefer that feature to be called "contacts" so I'm wondering if it is possible to rewrite/replace a phrase in a search engine friendly url.

So right now the urls are something like www.domain.com/community/friends with Joomla SEF urls turned on.

We would like to change that using an .htaccess rewrite rule to be  www.domain.com/community/contacts

This would also apply to other urls such as /community/friends/invite etc

Is that possible?

Thank you in advance for any help
Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

Provided you are not using any 3rd party sef extensions:

You should edit the menu item name Friends which you find in the community menu.

Administrator -> menus -> Jomsocial Toolbar

and edit the Friends menu item (change its alias as well, that's the part that will be used for generating the page url).

Clear the cache and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've tried that but it remains as friends and when I asked JomSocial devs they said you would need to do major hacking to get that changed. Hence why they said only option would be to try htaccess url rewrites?

Comment: You're right, I can't recall how I did it! It was an old site and I don't have it anymore, and I didn't remember hacking jomsocial for that purpose - but I must have, or maybe I had sh404 deal with it. Sorry I can't make tests as I no longer have the installation up.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by enabling the SEO friendly url options from Joomla.

You have to change the alias name to the name that you are looking for. Please use the following steps for creating links.

Steps :

Go to menu to create links.

Give the name to menu.

Select menu item types to friend link from jomsocial.

Change the alias to the name that you are looking for. Here it will be contact.

Thats it.

It will reflect to all the url (sub) for friends.